# someone posing as blockchain support cleaned out my account after telling me my account had been compromised/cloned

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, fraud, blockchain-wallet-app

Sent a support ticket to blockchain because my validation email wallet ID's changed each time. (Using computer)
This morning my account is cleaned out!  Have transaction details and addresses it went to as well as times of transactions. 
It's probably a lost cause other than getting a hacker to fix it.. 
Does anyone know if I can do anything about it?

Comment: Nope.  In the future be ***extremely*** careful giving out account information, especially private keys, or using a compromised computer.

Answer (score 0):

Afraid not, you've fallen victim to a phishing scam. Never trust any website which asks for your password, seed words, or private keys.